# Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an animated logo 
inspiration : http://codepen.io/pavlunya/pen/OPmVem

I am getting error when I use `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName`

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8x33crr/)

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is always useful.

Answer (score 5):

The reason `p` is null is because `document.getElementById` returns a single dom node, not an array.  You do not need the `[0]` at the end on line 4.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` doesn't return an array; just remove the `[0]` on your selector.